# Why does my Windows 7 laptop emit a buzz when I left click my Desktop?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, thinkpad, noise

I have a Lenovo T410s with SSD. I have a JPEG image as my background (I think MS got rid of those annoying Active Desktops AFAIK).

When I left-click on the Desktop, I hear a buzz.

Has anyone else experienced this? Any more information that might be relevant, just ask in the comments.

**More information**

1. The sound seems to come from the laptop chassis.
2. I hear the sound even when I right click on the desktop of my secondary external monitor.
3. I'm not using headphones or microphones.
4. The sound is visible even when sound is on mute.
5. It does not happen when I right click outside the desktop (e.g., right click in Chrome or MS Word).

Comment: Are you using headphones when you hear the buzzing?

Comment: Nope. Just to be sure, I turned off speakers and muted sound. Still hear the buzz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably the power supply or CPU hitting specific frequencies.  Try running a CPU intensive program and see if the issue goes away.